# Enable network connection transparently on demand

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

On Linux, I'm looking for a way to enable a network connection as soon as a program attempts to perform a network operation that would fail if that network connection were disabled, without the program even noticing something special went on behind the scenes.

More generally, is there a way to exec() a program image the moment the operating system realizes that a certain network operation is about to fail for a certain reason, then wait for that program to finish and, if the result is EXIT_SUCCESS, attempt the network operation again?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to exec() a program image the moment the operating system realizes that a certain network operation is about to fail for a certain reason, then wait for that program to finish and, if the result is EXIT_SUCCESS, attempt the network operation again?

No.

When dial-on-demand was used, it relied on retries which were not triggered by the successful connection.  A default route was maintained, with packets discarded until the connection was made, to avoid `Network unreachable` errors, which would end e.g. TCP connection attempts immediately.

I imagine old-style dial-on-demand also relied on longer DNS timeouts/retry counts than are used at present.  On a modern system it gives up after 15 seconds, [which does not seem long enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsNaR6FRuO0).

Dial on demand was totally a thing though, which I can imagine worked in most cases

> without the program even noticing something special went on behind the scenes.

### so how would i do it

If you try to dig up the old code, I'm pretty sure you'll find it was used for PPP specifically.  This might or might not be useful for certain modern mobile data connections.  But if it doesn't use PPP, it won't work with the old code.  The default route was assigned to the network interface e.g. `ppp0`, but the corresponding PPP daemon was run using the `ondemand` option and so didn't really make the connection until it was needed.

Comment: My specific case involves the set up of a mobile broadband connection with a huawei LTE module which sits into an embedded device. The end result of the whole setup procedure is a eth1 device being added to the system. You're thus suggesting I should write a sort of "proxy" network device that would be used as a default gateway and as soon as it received a packet would set up eth1 and forward that and all the other packets to it? I was hoping such a network device already existed.

Comment: On another thought, can't the IP filtering framework be _abused_ for this?

Comment: The dial-on-demand stuff was indeed in pppd and in fact still is. I don't think it'll help OP, though...